# How to Setting up Amazon EC2 with own OS and DB?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i got my own version of OS and DB
which are window server 2008 Hyper-V R2 and Sql server R2 2008
both in enterprise version
may i know how to configure it up and running ?
with amazon EC2, what other is a must combination to make it run ?
also how could i install the operating system and DNS ?
i never doing server before, but i just need something like VPS to support my development and testing. Amazon Ec2 seem the best and cheapest service due to only $1 per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a VMware virtual machine locally and then export that image to EC2. VMware will let you install and customize your operating system - so you can install your databases, etc.

With most operating systems you would need to export the virtual machine into a format that EC2 recognizes (either by converting the VMDK to raw and then bundling the image OR by bundling the volume from within the VM)

With Windows server 2008 virtual machines, AWS supports a direct import of the virtual machine. See the [AWS VM Import](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/) page for details.

You should be able to make additional modifications after the server has been imported if required.

Comment: but the thing is they still charge me although i'm using my own license >.<

Comment: Currently, you will be charged at the Windows instance rate, despite having your own license ( http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#When_I_import_a_VM_of_Windows_Server_2008,_who_is_responsible_for_supplying_the_operating_system_license ). AWS did have a pilot program ( http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/03/bring_your_own_ea_windows_server_license_to_ec2.html ) (now closed) which would allow you to temporarily transfer your license to them, so it can be expected that in the future they will support it.

Comment: Great =D can't wait to enjoy it ^^

Answer (score 1):

You could migrate your servers to clouds that allows you to use your own licensing like [ElasticHosts](http://elastichosts.com) or [CloudSigma](http://cloudsigma.com).

Your servers could be uploaded there via scripts they provide or via 3rd party tools like:

- CohesiveFT
- Racemi Cloudpath
- Migrate2iaas

Hope this helps!